# Database Design For Push Notifications Active Users in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, database-design, push-notification

I'm working on some Rest API architecture and I have to implement a push notification platform service for iOS and Android.

My question is, what would be the best solution for storing the device tokens of each platform?

I understand that the second one maybe is the more scalable one if they decide to develop a windowsPhone app for example in the future.

```
TABLE `push_active_users` (
   `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `device_token` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `is_ios` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `is_android` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL)
```

OR

```
TABLE `push_active_users` (
   `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `device_token` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `device_type_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL)

TABLE `device_type` (
   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL)
```

OR

```
TABLE `push_active_users_ios` (
   `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `device_token` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL)
TABLE `push_active_users_android` (
   `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `device_token` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL)
```

My choice would be the second one but i'm not sure if it's the best solution.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because the implementation for each platform (iOS, Android, Windows) will be different you might want to actually keep your `push_active_users` consistent for any platform and setup different `push_configuration` tables that each item in `push_active_users` can reference.

```
TABLE `push_active_users` (
`configuration_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`device_token` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL)

TABLE `push_configuration` (
`configuration_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`platform` varchar(255) NOT NULL)
```

If needed, you can also setup additional columns in the `push_configuration` table for any platform information need to setup push message with APNS or GCM, which is a big plus.

This way when you send a message you can get each `push_configuration` and simply send a message to all the `push_active_users` that it contains.